# how to avoid dbo in bcpy(bulk copy python) while pushing the data into sql server from python

Tags: python, sql-server, bcp

I am trying to push the data from pandas dataframe into a sql server table using bcpy in **python** script.

```
database : db_name
table : schema_name.table_name
```

but by default It creates the dbo schema while running and throw an error like below:

```
A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options. 
db_name.dbo.schema_name.table_name
```

actually, I gave the schema name as `schema_name`.

how to avoid the default schema name `dbo`?

If i gave the schema name,

```
database : database_name
schema : schema_name
table : table_name
```

It creates the `database_name.schema_name.table_name`.
but still its showing

```
A valid table name is required for in, out, or format options.
failed : Bcp command failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. BCP(Bulk Copy Program) utility for SQL Server should be installed in your machine.
2. database details should be in a dictionary form

   `sql_config = {database : database_name
   schema : schema_name
   table : table_name}`

If there is no schema name specified, by default `dbo` would be the schema name.

while fitting all the inputs into `bcp` command, the sql table name would be `database_name.schema_name.table_name`

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to mention the schema name while mentioning the table name.

You can use the below bcp command to upload the data from a csv file to the table. Write your dataframe into a csv file and then execute the below command.

```
df.to_csv("data.csv",index=False)
command = 'bcp "dbo.table_name" in "data.csv" -S"server_name" -d"DB_name" -F2 -c -t"," - U"user_name" -P"password" -e error.txt'
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I am trying this in python.

Answer (score 1):

Try mentioning database , schema and table name in square brackets and see if it works.

```
database :   [database_name]
schema   :   [schema_name]
table    :   [table_name]
```